# Font Awesome User Control Text Binding [Xamarin]

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, static

I am working on a Xamarin app and am trying to display a notification grid that renders some text along with a FontAwesome icon. The list of notifications are coming from an API so I need to display a custom icon per notification. I have the following `XAML`

```
<controls:FontAwesomeLabel Text="{Binding Icon}" TextColor="{Binding Colour}" />
```

This control is inside a `Grid` that's `ItemSource` is a List of objects that have an `Icon` and `Colour` property.

When I use the code shown in the first code snippet the FontAwesome icon will not render on the page. The `Icon` property all has values like so `\uf0ac`.

The funny thing is if I change the `Text` property code in the first snippet to

```
<controls:FontAwesomeLabel Text="{x:Static controls:Icon.FAGlobe}"
   TextColor="{Binding Colour}" />
```

So in the second example the `Text` property is referencing a static string that has the same code `\uf0ac`. But this time it renders the correct font awesome icon on the page.

This will not work for my scenario as the icon code is provided in the API call giving each notification tile its own icon.

What am I doing wrong when it comes to the `Text="{Binding Icon}"` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my model I was inheriting from `INotifyPropertyChanged` but for some reason I still had to do go old school with the binding to get it to work.

```
    private string _icon;
    public string Icon
    {
        get
        {
            return _icon;
        }
        set
        {
            _icon = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Icon"));
            }
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```